# Selenium Screenshots are weird and bad when zoomed in

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to take screenshots of some latex formulas on my website. I want to automate it using Selenium. At low zoom, the script produces good screenshots, but the latex equations are low resolution, which is not ideal:

[image]

At high zoom, if I inspect element and save screenshots, the pictures are great, but Selenium fails to take the same screenshots, instead taking bad screenshots like so:

[image]

Independently, regardless of zoom, sometimes screenshots will just be large white rectangles. I am wondering what the solution to this whole mess is.

Here is my script:

You'll need to
`pip install selenium pyautogui webdriver-manager

If you run it, it will create a temp folder in the run directory and put the images in there.

```py
import os
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
# from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import pyautogui

dry_run = False  # if False, don't save anything
save_to_temp_folder = True  # if True, save to temp folder instead of content/formulas (for previewing)
# chrome_options = Options()
# chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

driver.get('http://stemformulas.com/formulas')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

def zoom_in(times=1):
    for i in range(times):
        pyautogui.hotkey('command', '+')

# Find the list items within the specified <ul> element
ul_element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'ul.flex.flex-row.mt-8')
list_items = ul_element.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'li')

# Count the number of list items. Subtract one for the next button.
page_count = len(list_items) - 1
print(f"Found {page_count} pages of formulas")

# increase zoom to 400% for higher quality screenshots
# zoom_in(4)
# driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom = '200%'")

for i in range(1, page_count + 1): # iterate over pages
    print("Visiting page: ", i)
    # visit formulas page
    driver.get(f'http://stemformulas.com/formulas/page/{i}')

    # Find the section with class "grid-container mt-6"
    section = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'section.grid-container.mt-6')

    # Find all anchor elements within the section
    anchors = section.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'a')
    num_anchors = len(anchors)
    print(f"Found ", num_anchors, " formula grid items")

    # Iterate over the formula grid items
    for i in range(num_anchors):
        # if I iterate over the anchors they become stale so refetch section, anchors every time
        section = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'section.grid-container.mt-6')
        anchors = section.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'a')
        anchor = anchors[i]
        href = anchor.get_attribute('href')
        x_path = f"//*[@id=\"main-content\"]/section[2]/a[{i+1}]/div[1]"

        div = anchor.find_element(By.XPATH, x_path)
        div.location_once_scrolled_into_view # scroll into view
        # http://stemformulas.com/formulas/<folder_name>/
        folder_name = href.split('/')[-2]
        output_image_path = os.path.join("content", "formulas", folder_name, "preview.png")
        
        if dry_run:
            print(f"Would have screenshot div {div} to {output_image_path}")
        elif save_to_temp_folder:
            if not os.path.exists("temp"):
                os.mkdir("temp")
            if not os.path.exists(os.path.join("temp", folder_name)):
                os.mkdir(os.path.join("temp", folder_name))
            new_path = os.path.join("temp", folder_name, "preview.png")
            bits = div.screenshot_as_png
            with open(new_path, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(bits)
            print(f"Screenshot div {div} to {new_path}")
            time.sleep(1)
        else:
            bits = div.screenshot_as_png
            with open(output_image_path, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(bits)
            print(f"Screenshot div {div} to {output_image_path}")
            time.sleep(1) # if we don't sleep, elements become stale
```

Some stuff I've tried:

- Using `driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom = '400%'")` - lead to even worse pictures
- headless - did not resolve issue

Comment: What's your browser size/screen resolution? That will occasionally change screenshot quality

Comment: they look pretty good to me... the png compression may be losing some quality. These look like scalable vector graphics to me. Can you just grab the SVGs instead? Other option would be to do your own anti-aliasing and grab the raw bytes but I wouldn't expect you'd see much difference. A screenshot will be fixed (rastorized) to your screen's resolution.  If this is a font, you might also lose some of the smoothing that's built-in for display when it's compressed to PNG.

Comment: I want a much higher resolution, and it's possible at higher resolution, just not to Selenium. Katex to SVG is not supported yet. A screenshot shouldnt' be fixed to a screen's resolution, because I am screenshotting elements and not the entire browser, right?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the script hasn't given the browser time to actually finish rendering the content.  try waiting for it to finish.  Maybe when you search for the section:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
section = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'section.grid-container.mt-6'))
```